# Who would be interested in a Kanban TFS Process Template?

Tags: tfs, kanban

I'm thinking about building a TFS Process Template for Kanban.  I just wanted to gauge the interest....

Comment: While this is valid topic to talk about, it seems to be not appropriate as a Question on SO: Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers. As you'll probably know now, the support is going to be better with every update of 2012/2013 (We have a [kanban board, yay](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/work-from-the-kanban-board-vs) ).

Answer (score 6):

We have been using TFS and kanban together for several years now.  Since kanban can be used to model any process, it doesn't make sense to have process templates.  The gap is in the visualization of work items.

There is an awesome tool called TeamWorks by SEP that can do kanban with TFS right out of the box.  Plus it is free!

Check it out: http://www.sep.com/labs/teamworks/

Answer (score 4):

Supporting Kanban inside TFS is feasible but it is not for the fainted heart.

First, you will need expertise about how to edit TFS process template. And it is not because you will need to create  a specific TFS process template for Kanban. If you are serious about Scrum and Kanban, I strongly suggest that you start (your process improvement) with the [Visual Studio Scrum 1.0](http://tp://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/59ac03e3-df99-4776-be39-1917cbfc5d8e) template released by Microsoft in July 2010 and change it as you go.  Be warned that you will need to manually edit and change the TFS process template as your process evolve (add or remove state).

Second, you will need to find the right skin to turn TFS into a Kanban board.  Today, tools like [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com) provides web interface to turn TFS into Scrum (not Kanban). However, through configuration you can adapt our task board to support multiple states (and behave a little bit like a kanban board).  As specified by Scrum, [Urban Turtle](http://urbanturtle.com) task board contains only three columns (To do, In progress, Done).  However, one column can host many state. For example, it is possible to drag a card from one state to another state while keeping the card inside the  “In progress” column. As your process evolved, be warned that you will need to manually edit and change the Urban Turtle configuration file to map the new state with color. FYI, adding a specific Kanban board (which will not requires manual edits) is part of Urban Turtle roadmap. However, it is not rank high in our product backlog.

Discloser: I work with the Urban Turtle team. So do not take my words. Instead, read what Brian Harry from Microsoft wrote in his blog a few days ago: "...awesome Scrum experience for TFS." You can read Brian Harry's blog post [here](http://urbanturtle.com/awesome).

Comment: I will have to look into Urban Turtle more closely.  And I knew that you worked with the Urban Turtle team.  We met at the ALM Summit!

Answer (score 2):

Kanban is not a software development life cycle methodology but a process change methodology as I have written in my post:

[There should never be a Kanban process template for Team Foundation Server(TFS)](http://hakanforss.wordpress.com/2010/10/07/there-should-never-be-a-kanban-process-template-for-team-foundation-servertfs/)

There is a great need for tooling for TFS that would make the use of Kanban better on TFS.

I'm working on one Kanban tool for TFS that will try to visualize the flow of work. Please take a look at the early version at codeplex: [Visual WIP](http://visualwip.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 0):

Actually we use Kanaban and TFS and my opinion is that TFS is more of an obstacle here than help. We basically reduced TFS role to bug tracking tool and code repo.

One of strengths of Kanban board is its visual design which is very intuitive. It can't really be substituted with a set of forms organized in the flow.

What more, teams tend to use "hardware" white/cork board with sticky notes whenever they can, namely whenever they are co-located. And even if they aren't they usually try to find a software tool which is as simple as possible. You can say a lot about TFS but not that it is a simple tool.

Personally I think that's not a very good idea. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  Have you tried the Work Item Manager from Telerik?  It's a pretty nice (and free) way of visualizing your digital cork board for kanban.  I've used TFS 2010 since Beta1 and don't find it all that complicated given all that it can do.  If I were on a small team I might agree with you that a corkboard would be a good way to go but it provides zero visibility to anyone outside of my team....

Comment: I would tend to agree with you Devlife.  Physical boards are really nice, but I to use WIM from Telerik.  I also find the Urban Turtle board great.  If you could put together a web based, ajaxy WIM equivalent, I think many would jump at it.

Comment: I haven't used Telerik's WIM. I played with Kanbanery (kanbanery.com) for some time and if I decided to go with a software I'd probably tend to choose something like that.
Of course I agree that the need of software board appears when the team is distributed.